# Is it possible to automatically import certificates in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, certificate

When deploying Firefox on Linux is it possible to have certificates automatically imported using something similar to autoconfig?

I've searched around a bit and found some instructions for doing this, but all of them seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and works the same on any supported platform (including Linux).

You mainly have two possibilities :

## Use https://mike.kaply.com/cck2/

It's a Firefox extension that you can use to customize many things in Firefox (including adding CA certificates). It generates a zip file that you deploy on top of Firefox install dir (something like /usr/lib/firefox on Linux). It's probably the most easy way to do it.

## Use autoconfig

I've used it to deploy CA certificates in corporate environment (not tested with other types of certificates). It also allows to do any customization you would need.

First of all, you need to configure an autoconfig file, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment#Configuration for how to do that.

Then, you need to put your certificate file(s) inside defaults/pref subdirectory (ex: /usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref), put the function below in your autoconfig file, and call it :

```
// This imports a root certificate into Firefox
// The certificate has to be in defaults/pref directory of Firefox
// Source : http://xulfr.org/forums/read.php?1,8256
function importCert(certFileName) {
    var BEGIN_CERT = "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----";
    var END_CERT = "-----END CERTIFICATE-----";

    var x509certdb = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/security/x509certdb;1"];
    var certDB ;
    try {
        // For Firefox <=32
        certDB = x509certdb.getService(Components.interfaces.nsIX509CertDB2);
    }
    catch (exc) {
        // For Firefox >=33
        certDB = x509certdb.getService(Components.interfaces.nsIX509CertDB);
    }

    var ioService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);

    var scriptableStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/scriptableinputstream;1"]
                                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableInputStream);


    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O#Getting_special_files
    Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");  
    var certFile = FileUtils.getFile("PrfDef", [certFileName]);

    // http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tools/certutil.html
    var trustFlags = "C,C,C";

    var channel = ioService.newChannelFromURI(ioService.newFileURI(certFile));
    var input = channel.open();
    scriptableStream.init(input);
    var certfile = scriptableStream.read(input.available());
    scriptableStream.close();
    input.close();

    certfile = certfile.replace(/[\r\n]/g, "");
    begin = certfile.indexOf(BEGIN_CERT);
    end = certfile.indexOf(END_CERT);
    cert = certfile.substring(begin + BEGIN_CERT.length, end);

    certDB.addCertFromBase64(cert, trustFlags, "");
}
importCert("myCert.pem");
```

Your certificate needs to be in ASCII Base64 X509 format (a text file starting with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----).